# Html code in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I searching codename one API and found there is a HTMLElement, HTMLComponent and HTMLUtils class are there and under HTMLElemrent has fields like TAG_body etc... If i am not wrong using this we can write HTML code, please correct me if i am wrong. Also i want to know how i can use that TAG fields of HTMLElements i tried it with creating it's object but may be not doing in correct way. Please show me correct ways to implements of these classes and also share the core purpose of this classes.

Regards,
jeny

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong.

HTMLComponent is an HTML viewer component used in older devices (blackberries, J2ME devices). This code is unused in modern devices.

You can view HTML/WebContent using the web browser component which automatically picks the best web viewer for your platform.